# App is crashing, I know it has something to do with "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "$19.00""(in log), but I dont know how to fix it

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, r.java-file

Its basically a calculator app. The problem occurs when the user goes back to edit the edittexts that they previously edited, and clicks the calculate button for the second time. I understand the answer is smack in my face but I really know very little about this so I cant find the solution. I have been stuck for 2 weeks. Thank you for your help in advance, I know this is a terrible question but I am really stuck. Replacement code is much appreciated as I am a novice!

.java code-

```
package washingtondeli.groupboxlunchesestimateandordering;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class CapitolhillActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mButton;

    EditText sand1;
    EditText sand2;
    EditText sand3;
    EditText sand4;
    EditText sand5;
    EditText sand6;
    EditText sand7;

    EditText extra1;
    EditText extra2;
    EditText extra3;
    EditText extra4;
    EditText extra5;
    EditText extra6;


    TextView result1;
    TextView result2;
    TextView result3;
    TextView result4;
    TextView result5;
    TextView result6;
    TextView result7;

    TextView extraresult1;
    TextView  extraresult2;
    TextView extraresult3;
    TextView extraresult4;
    TextView extraresult5;
    TextView extraresult6;

    CheckBox delivery;
    TextView subtotal;
    TextView total;
    int d;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capitolhill);

        sand1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sand1);
        sand2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sand2);
        sand3= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sand3);
        sand4= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sand4);
        sand5= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sand5);
        sand6= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sand6);
        sand7= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sand7);

        extra1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.extra1);
        extra2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.extra2);
        extra3= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.extra3);
        extra4= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.extra4);
        extra5= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.extra5);
        extra6= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.extra6);

        result1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result1);
        result2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result2);
        result3= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result3);
        result4= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result4);
        result5= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result5);
        result6= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result6);
        result7= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result7);

        extraresult1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.extraresult1);
        extraresult2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.extraresult2);
        extraresult3= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.extraresult3);
        extraresult4= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.extraresult4);
        extraresult5= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.extraresult5);
        extraresult6= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.extraresult6);

        subtotal= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtotal);
        total= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        final CheckBox delivery= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        delivery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (delivery.isChecked()) {
                    d = 25;
                } else {
                    d = 0;
                }
            }
        });

        mButton =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (delivery.isChecked()) {
                    d = 25;
                } else {
                    d = 0;
                }

                calculate2();
            }
        });
    }

    public void calculate2() {
        //get entered texts from the edittexts,and convert to integers.
        Integer value1 = Integer.parseInt(sand1.getText().toString());
        Integer value2 = Integer.parseInt(sand2.getText().toString());
        Integer value3 = Integer.parseInt(sand3.getText().toString());
        Integer value4 = Integer.parseInt(sand4.getText().toString());
        Integer value5 = Integer.parseInt(sand5.getText().toString());
        Integer value6 = Integer.parseInt(sand6.getText().toString());
        Integer value7 = Integer.parseInt(sand7.getText().toString());

        Integer value8 = Integer.parseInt(extra1.getText().toString());
        Integer value9 = Integer.parseInt(extra2.getText().toString());
        Integer value10 = Integer.parseInt(extra3.getText().toString());
        Integer value11 = Integer.parseInt(extra4.getText().toString());
        Integer value12 = Integer.parseInt(extra5.getText().toString());
        Integer value13 = Integer.parseInt(extra6.getText().toString());

        Integer valuesubtotal = Integer.parseInt(subtotal.getText().toString());
        Integer valuetotal = Integer.parseInt(total.getText().toString());
        //do the calculation

        Double calculatedValue1 = (9.5*value1);
        Double calculatedValue2 = (9.5*value2);
        Double calculatedValue3 = (9.5*value3);
        Double calculatedValue4 = (9.5*value4);
        Double calculatedValue5 = (9.5*value5);
        Double calculatedValue6 = (9.5*value6);
        Double calculatedValue7 = (9.5*value7);

        Double calculatedValue8 = (2.25*value8);
        Double calculatedValue9=(1.5*value9) ;
        Double calculatedValue10=(3.5*value10) ;
        Double calculatedValue11 =(3.95*value11) ;
        Double calculatedValue12 = (3.5*value12);
        Double calculatedValue13 = (2.95*value13);

        Double calculatedsubtotal = (d+calculatedValue1+calculatedValue2+calculatedValue3+calculatedValue4+calculatedValue5+calculatedValue6+calculatedValue7+calculatedValue8+calculatedValue9+calculatedValue10+calculatedValue11+calculatedValue12+calculatedValue13);
        Double calculatedtotal = ((.1*calculatedsubtotal)+calculatedsubtotal);

        //set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
        result1.setText("$"+String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue1 ));
        result2.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue2 ));
        result3.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue3 ));
        result4.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue4 ));
        result5.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue5 ));
        result6.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue6 ));
        result7.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue7 ));

        extraresult1.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue8 ));
        extraresult2.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue9 ));
        extraresult3.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue10 ));
        extraresult4.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue11));
        extraresult5.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue12));
        extraresult6.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue13));

        subtotal.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedsubtotal ));
        total.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedtotal ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your exception stacktrace with your question. It looks like you're not parsing your user's input correctly.

Comment: Perhaps you really want to use a NumberFormat currency instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before call (textview/editText).getText().toString(), remove the $ symbol and use double instead int.

Try this:

```
    String total = "$10.5";
    String strAmount = total.replace("$","");
    double value = Double.valueOf(strAmount);
    Log.e("VALUE", String.valueOf(value));
```

Example:

```
public void calculate2() {
    //get entered texts from the edittexts,and convert to integers.
    Double value1 = moneyToDouble(sand1.getText().toString());
    Double value2 = moneyToDouble(sand2.getText().toString());
    Double value3 = moneyToDouble(sand3.getText().toString());
    Double value4 = moneyToDouble(sand4.getText().toString());
    Double value5 = moneyToDouble(sand5.getText().toString());
    Double value6 = moneyToDouble(sand6.getText().toString());
    Double value7 = moneyToDouble(sand7.getText().toString());

    Double value8 = moneyToDouble(extra1.getText().toString());
    Double value9 = moneyToDouble(extra2.getText().toString());
    Double value10 = moneyToDouble(extra3.getText().toString());
    Double value11 = moneyToDouble(extra4.getText().toString());
    Double value12 = moneyToDouble(extra5.getText().toString());
    Double value13 = moneyToDouble(extra6.getText().toString());

    Double valuesubtotal = moneyToDouble(subtotal.getText().toString());
    Double valuetotal = moneyToDouble(total.getText().toString());
    //do the calculation

    Double calculatedValue1 = (9.5*value1);
    Double calculatedValue2 = (9.5*value2);
    Double calculatedValue3 = (9.5*value3);
    Double calculatedValue4 = (9.5*value4);
    Double calculatedValue5 = (9.5*value5);
    Double calculatedValue6 = (9.5*value6);
    Double calculatedValue7 = (9.5*value7);

    Double calculatedValue8 = (2.25*value8);
    Double calculatedValue9=(1.5*value9) ;
    Double calculatedValue10=(3.5*value10) ;
    Double calculatedValue11 =(3.95*value11) ;
    Double calculatedValue12 = (3.5*value12);
    Double calculatedValue13 = (2.95*value13);

    Double calculatedsubtotal = (d+calculatedValue1+calculatedValue2+calculatedValue3+calculatedValue4+calculatedValue5+calculatedValue6+calculatedValue7+calculatedValue8+calculatedValue9+calculatedValue10+calculatedValue11+calculatedValue12+calculatedValue13);
    Double calculatedtotal = ((.1*calculatedsubtotal)+calculatedsubtotal);

    //set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
    result1.setText("$"+String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue1 ));
    result2.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue2 ));
    result3.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue3 ));
    result4.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue4 ));
    result5.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue5 ));
    result6.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue6 ));
    result7.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue7 ));

    extraresult1.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue8 ));
    extraresult2.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue9 ));
    extraresult3.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue10 ));
    extraresult4.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue11));
    extraresult5.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue12));
    extraresult6.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue13));

    subtotal.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedsubtotal ));
    total.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedtotal ));
}

private Double moneyToDouble(String total){

    String strAmount = total.replace("$","");
    double value = Double.valueOf(strAmount);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: I am really bad at this, would you mind editing my code, because I am really lost. I know it's bad to just ask for someone to do it for me it's just that it's been 2 weeks and 3 questions later and I can't figure it out

Comment: so do i copy and paste this into my calculation2? I have to do the bottom part for every value though right?

Comment: Yes, copy and paste the calculation2 method and the moneyToDouble method, tell me if you have another issue with this.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I have another question if you dont mind. When I click calculate, the screen scrolls up to the last edit text i edited within the scrollview. I want the screen to not scroll after clicking calculate.

Comment: :) , please post your activity layout (xml) to help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your $ sign. It is causing the issue since it is not a number. Also change your variable type to double.

Comment: Eh, [I wouldn't be so quick to change the variable type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

Comment: I am really bad at this, would you mind editing my code, because I am really lost. I know it's bad to just ask for someone to do it for me it's just that it's been 2 weeks and 3 questions later and I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

It is crashing second time **because $ gets added to your edit text value** and when you do getString on that edittext it will give you string appended with $ symbol. You have to remove $ symbol when you do calculation second time

**Showing you for one value according to your code**

```
String value=subtotal.getText().toString();
String replace=value.replace("$","");
Integer valuesubtotal = Integer.parseInt(replace);
```

Comment: I am really bad at this, would you mind editing my code, because I am really lost. I know it's bad to just ask for someone to do it for me it's just that it's been 2 weeks and 3 questions later and I can't figure it out

Comment: where do i put this exactly... sorry im really lost

Comment: Before this line `Integer valuesubtotal = Integer.parseInt(subtotal.getText().toString());`

Comment: and i do this for every value?

Comment: every value with $ symbol in it

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure your way would have worked too, its just that she gave me the copy paste lol lazy  i know